# Compare String on C

Tags: c, string, compare, string-comparison

I have written this code where i want to input a text, say `"helloWorld"` and then compare it such that if it matches the entered text then it should print the text 101 times. But, it is not working as it does not seem to compare the string in the `if (string == "helloWorld")` and it directly skips to the `else` part. Please provide necessary details on how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()

{
    int i;
    char string[30];
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter the string 'helloWorld' if you wanna see magic\n");
    scanf ("%s", string);
    printf("Your enterred Input is %s\n", string);
    if (string == "helloWorld")
    {
        for (i=0;i<=100;i++)
        {
            printf("%s\n",string);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid Input\n");
    }
    getch();
}
```

Also, I know that in C if we enter a string using `char variable[sting_length]` in C, we have to enter the string **without** any spaces. But, is there any way to enter the string like "Hello World" and still have the whole thing printed/compared altogether?

Comment: You can't compare C strings with the `==` operator.  That will compare their addresses, not their contents.  Look up the standard `strcmp` function.

Comment: "we have to enter the string without any spaces" - Huh? If "We" means the people from your class, this might be a restriction by your teacher. But for the rest this is nonsense and no way mandated by the C standard.

Answer (score -2):

In order to read the string with a space, you could create a loop that reads characters until it reaches a new line.

```
int i = 0;
char inputChar = ' ';
char* string = new char[STRING_SIZE];
do
{
     getch(inputChar);
     string[i] = inputChar;
     i++;
} while (inputChar != '\n' && i < STRING_SIZE);
```

In this code, STRING_SIZE is whatever size of array you choose.

In order to compare the strings, you have to check each element in order to verify that they are the same.

```
char compare[] = "Hello, world!";
int i = 0;
bool areEqual = true;
while (areEqual && compare[i] != '\n')
{
     if(compare[i] != string[i])
     {
         areEqual = false;
     }
}
```

Using these two sections of code, you should be able to read a string with spaces then compare it to any string of your choosing.  The strings may also have different lengths.

Comment: `getch` is not a standard function. And there are simpler and better ways. For a starter: use standard functions, don't reinvent the wheel!